# Can't update mysql rows using eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm new in Laravel and Eloquent ORM. I'm try to update row if it exists, but always getting an error. Here is the code:

```
public static function UpdateVisit(){

    $ThisVisit = Visit::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();  // is this first visit? 
    echo $ThisVisit;

    if (!$ThisVisit){
        $ThisVisit = New Visit;
        }
        $ThisVisit->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $ThisVisit->ip = Request::getClientIp();
        $ThisVisit->browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $ThisVisit->save();


}
```

When record is new, it works well. But when I'm trying to update, I am getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `visits` set `browser` = Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16, `updated_at` = 2013-12-24 20:03:59 where `id` is null)

My table:

```
user_id  |  browser  |  ip  |  created_at  |  updated_at
```

Can somebody help me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe `$ThisVisit->user_id = Auth::user()->ip;` or `$ThisVisit->user_id = Auth::user()->user_id;`? You might have have either mixed up `id` with `ip` or even `user_id` It's hard to say because you have similar columns. Also `$ThisVisit = Visit::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();` might need to be `$ThisVisit = Visit::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->user_id)->first();` or `ip` hard to say, try both.

Comment: You are trying to reference `id` when it is called `user_id`

Comment: $ThisVisit = Visit::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first(); Here i trying to detect do i have row in DB , where 'user_id' equal loged user`s id. User`s id i store in table users in column named `id`

Comment: On the visit model, did you define an identifier column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easy solution of your problem is create `id` field in your table. Laravel, By default will consider `id` field as `primary key`.

```
id | user_id  |  browser  |  ip  |  created_at  |  updated_at
```

**Or**

---

This is not recommended as i think your `user_id` is not unique in the table and user can browse the website using various browsers including mobile.

---

**use `user_id` as primary key.**

In your **`Visit`** model:

```
protected $primaryKey = "user_id";

//will prevent auto increment your user_id
protected $incrementing = false;
```